# modal close button with translate3d

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was having an issue with scrolling on an Ipad with a quickview modal. The problem was I was trying to scroll on the modal but the page itself was scrolling, not the modal. I used `.modal * {-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)` which fixed the scrolling issue. However now the modal x button doesn't close the modal. If I touch outside the modal it closes, however I would like to keep the functionality of the close button as not all users would know to touch outside the modal.

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <svg class="icon close--modal">
              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://10.30.2.54:300/images/sprite.svg#close--modal"></use>
            </svg>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Quick View</h4>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the CSS selectors, figured it out. Hope this helps anyone in the future

```
.modal * :not(.modal-header *) {-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
```

This will apply the rule to all the children of .modal except the modal header and its children